# Why isn't this simple opacity animation working in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, transition

I was trying to make a simple fade in fade out animation for a text but when I try to do it this way it doesn't work. Theres no smooth increase and decrease in opacity it just jumps to full and no opacity.

```
struct Test: View {
    @State var showing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Toggle") {
                self.showing.toggle()
            }
            
            if showing {
                Text("Hello")
                    .transition(.opacity)
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work as intended? I was expecting this to have a smooth fade in fade out transition when the Text was inserted and removed from the View Hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no-one left to animate when `showing` is `false`. Instead use the following:

```
VStack {
    if showing {
        Text("Hello")
            .transition(.opacity)
    }
}.animation(.easeInOut)   // << here !!
```

Comment: I don't understand why it works like that?